# Proving a certain determinant $\left|\det A\right|$ is complete square

Tags: number-theory, matrices, contest-math

Consider the following matrix
$$
A_{ij}=
\begin{cases}
1\quad\text{ if }\space (i+j)\space\text{ is prime,}\\
0\quad\text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
How can one prove that $\left|\det A\right|$ is a complete square?

Comment: I assume we are talking here about an $n\times n$ matrix, with the indices satisfying $1\leq i,j \leq n$?

Comment: @OldJohn: Is the induction on $n$ applicable here?

Comment: probably, but I am not sure yet!

Comment: @OldJohn: It seems that this matrix looks symmetric.

Comment: For $6 \times 6$, the determinant is $-1$. See [here.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant+of+{{1,1,0,1,0,1},{1,0,1,0,1,0},{0,1,0,1,0,0},{1,0,1,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0,0,1},{1,0,0,0,1,0}}). Ah, but he's taking the modulus.. Anyway, some numerical data: For $n =4,5,6$, the answer is $0,1,-1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a problem posed at an annual contest for undergraduates called IMC (International Mathematics Contest). The official site of the site http://www.imc-math.org . It was the fifth problem of the second day (year 2008), which means it is pretty hard to solve. Here is a reference of the official site http://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc2008/day2_solutions.pdf . Also there is a discussion here at artofproblemsolving forum http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=79&t=217339 .

Comment: I faces this problem on a mathematical battle at Saint-Petersburg.

Comment: I think there are too many competitions for the problems to be all original..